# Higgs Boson from Condensed Matter Physics

Tags: condensed-matter, history, higgs

I have heard it being said that the Higgs Boson's necessity and conceptual origin was first seen in the field of Condensed Matter Physics. Could someone elaborate on this?

Comment: Mistrust most of what you hear. The definitive, sound, history of the subject, detailed by the late  [Kibble, an original superhero thereof](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Englert-Brout-Higgs-Guralnik-Hagen-Kibble_mechanism_%28history%29) which references Anderson's early inchoate efforts should be read carefully. This question does not belong on this site.

Comment: This is a very complex subject and you will want to read several versions of the story to gain a full perspective. Besides the links in the above comments, you should also read the Wikipedia Higgs bob

Comment: Boson site as well as an excellent article in physics today a couple years ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with the history of physics, rather than directly with  a physics concept

Comment: @CountTo10 I would say that based on the criteria of the first answer here: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/156/ this question is suitable, since it asks about the development of a physical theory. On the other hand, it is somewhat broad.

Comment: @Rococo TBH, I really wanted to answer it, (and I  handwrote a quick draft, because I wanted to be able to leave the personalities/names  out of it completely) and I wanted for other users to sort  me out on my understanding.  But it's history and to get the physics in as well would create a long answer, I feel. On balance, no.

Answer (score -1):

The mathematical methods that Higgs used to prove the existence Higgs boson where previously used in the field of condensed matter physics to solve different problems that have a similar structure to those in particle physics. Higgs took those mathematical methods and adapted them to solve particle physics problems, discovering his Bosson.

Comment: That was the essence of my point above. Neither you, nor anyone, for that matter, in good faith, could reference and document the statements you made. You might not appreciate the Higgs is "debris" and not logically necessary at all, and Anderson's parting sidetone-liner  in his 1963 paper largely misses the mark. The Nobel committee did its homework and interminable tendentious remarks cannot alter the published record. Condensed matter physics may utilize the Higgs mechanism, but hardly the "debris" Higgs--the σ.

Comment: Note [Littlewood-Varma](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0109409) first appeared in just 1981.

Comment: In fact, it was Nambu himself, the "owner" of the theorem, who identified the Littlewood-Varma massive modes with a Higgs analog, well into the 80s!

Comment: Can you give a reference for this remark from Nambu?